# iphone: what event will be fired if we close a notofiaction without viewing it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

I have a situation say I have to print Notification viewed when local notification is viewed and Notification closed when close button of notification is clicked basically I want to know if we have an event/method which is fired once the notification's cancel button is pressed.

If this is not possible then do we have a method which got fired when the notification is displayed or pushed?

Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app isn't running, so there is no way to interact with the OS.
The OS will display the localnotification, thus there is no way to either check if the notification is displayed or the cancel button is pressed.

Comment: ok suppose my app is running and then I receive a notification now is this thing resolvable??

Comment: If your app is running then the appdelegate will recieve the notification. Then it's up to you to show the notification, with for example an UIAlertView.